# How to print out a poster with an image from a Netflix show?

Tags: posters, digital-printing

I want to preface this with saying that I am not positive this question should be posted here (mulled about putting in the Arts & Crafts SE) but I decided that people here would have the most relevant experience.
  Anyway, I was watching Our Planet on my big flat screen TV and I became in awe of a freeze-frame from the opening scene. I decided that I would love to have this image as a poster. However, I have no idea how to take an image from a Netflix show and then have it printed out in high quality to be framed as a large poster. How do I go about doing this? What website/software/company do I use?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Didnt downvote but you do understand that you are basically asking how to do a copyright  violation, of the kind that people on this site live by. Its a bit like asking how to pirate software , except your pirating  a image.

Comment: Hello Alek, welcome to GDSE. You are coming dangerously close to asking for help stealing something, as also pointed out by joojaa. Wouldn't it be better to just check posters for sale online? There's literally thousands of options of high-quality nature posters available, without having to worry about copyright. For the same cost as a print of a medium quality screen capture you could have a high quality legitimate poster on you wall! Maybe they even carry the specific image you want.

Comment: Have to say that I think purchasing a genuine movie/nature poster would be better than any result you could possibly get from a screen capture of a movie. So apart from anything else (including the trouble you might get into), it's just not worth doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Well...

- **First concern is copyright.** You can't just take anything you see and use it as you wish without infringing upon copyrights, unless you have permission. Now, that being posted, for your own use, in your own home, and as a one-off piece, you're probably okay. I'm **not** a lawyer, but that sounds like "*[fair use](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/)*" to me.
- **Second concern, how to get a good quality image.** If possible an image search for the image you want to use. In lieu of an actual image format....anything broadcast is at best 1920x1080 resolution. I don't believe Netflix broadcasts in 4k. So 1080 is as good as it gets. You'd be better served by viewing the broadcast at full screen on a desktop computer with a large monitor and taking a screen grab of the image you want. **However**, some online video players will *purposefully* prevent screen grabs of their content to prevent piracy. So, you'll just have have to try. If you can't screen cap anything, then you may need to purchase the content from somewhere as a dvd or somewhere which allows downloads. And even then it's a 50/50 shot if you can screencap the content still.
- **Third .. size.....** lets assume you got a screen cap that is 1080.... That size will generally mean a ~6.5x3.5"" image at typical 300ppi print resolution. You can sometimes get away with a lower resolution such as 150ppi. So, perhaps a ~12x7" image. Anything larger and you'll probably need to allow Photoshop, or some image editor, to [interpolate](http://www.americaswonderlands.com/image_resizing.htm) the pixels for an enlargement. This isn't *always* bad, especially for something like a poster where the viewing distance is greater. The farther away something is viewed, the lower PPI you can use to a degree.
- **Forth is file format.** If you find an image and get it to a correct size, you'l want to save it as a JPG  most likely at the maximum quality.
- **Lastly, reproduction.** You can sometimes get quick-copy shops (like Kinkos) to run a single print for you. They have large format inkjet printers just for this sort of thing. You *might* run into copyright issues here. Sometimes employees don't like running things you *clearly* don't have the right to, or it may be store policy. So, you'll just have to speak with them.

---

To me.. this is a great deal of effort for something as simple as a one-off poster for my wall.

Comment: +1 from me!  I've found that the copyright issue can be very problematic if you are not printing the images on your own printer.  Here in the UK at least, some of these photo printing services/kiosks will ask specifically if the image is yours, or if you have permission to print it.  I once took some photographs of a friend, using my DSLR. She went to a supermarket photo kiosk to have them printed, and they refused point blank. I had to give her a letter stating that I was the photographer and that I gave her permission to have them printed.